Mifos X Fineract - Fineract API not running on localhost:8080
I followed this installation guide to get
I get the error
Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/fineract-provider/actuator/info: 404
I have used Option #2 (Fineract War) and I have opted to go for mariadb connector over mysql
I have also used my actual password here. My assumption was that this should be the case
fineract.tenant.password=${FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_PWD:fineract011}
These are logs from my tomcat service indicating that the war file has been deployed by tomcat
14-Oct-2024 15:55:57.571 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.96/webapps/fineract-provider.war]
14-Oct-2024 15:55:57.832 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.96/webapps/fineract-provider.war] has finished in [260] ms
Please help me understand why this does not work even though the Mifos UI works
Please also guide me on the changes that would be required for this work via SSL and for my mifos UI to show the actual URL and not the defaults below
Mifos 231231 -
Fineract    -
http://localhost:8080
